# Is it true that all monotonic and bounded FUNCTIONS have a finite limit at $+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is it true that all monotonic and bounded FUNCTIONS have a finite limit at $+\infty$? If not, what if the functions are further continuous?

Comment: You mean from R to R ?

Comment: Yes, for all $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do. The limit is simply the supremum of the function.

Comment: You’re obviously correct, but you haven’t proven it formally

Comment: @AdamRubinson True. Now that I told OP what the limit is an attempt can be made by OP to prove it. I am here to help if need be.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking of posting my own answer with a formal proof based on the definitions. (Obviously the proof will be quite tedious, but that doesn’t mean it isn’t worthwhile)